# deploy an php web site

Tags: php, codeigniter, deployment

I need help please.
I hosted a website designed with codeigniter on a remote server, but I can not access the pages.Jai as 404 page not found error.

Here is the contents of the config.php file

```
$ config ['base_url'] ='http://www.SitePhp';
$ config ['index_page'] ='';
```

Here is the content of the .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets/|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^ (. *)$ index.php/$ 1 [L]
```

Thank you.

Comment: I see *a lot* of spaces that shouldn't be there. Are they really there in your `config.php` and `.htaccess` files or did you add those for our benefit?

Comment: ok. i'll rewrite them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and shared host open mod_rewrite module.

```
$config['base_url'] ='http://www.SitePhp.com/';
```

will be

```
http://www.SitePhp.com etc.
```